# Показать элементы с определенным значением атрибута

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. У меня есть несколько элементов с некоторыми значениями `data-value`. Помимо этого есть `select`, который указывает на то, какие элементы должны показываться. Если значение этого `select'а` равно `0`, то показываться должны все блоки. Как можно это осуществить? Заранее спасибо.

```js
function Values(){
  val = $("#values").val();
  
  if(val > 0){
    //тут код показа блоков со значением data-value, которое равно значению val (это требуется)
  } else {
    //тут код показа всех блоков (это тоже требуется)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select onchange="Values();" id="values">
  <option value="0">All</option>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<div data-value="1"></div>
<div data-value="1"></div>
<div data-value="2"></div>
<div data-value="3"></div>
<div data-value="2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Values() {
  var val = $("#values").val();
  if( val > 0 ){
    $('.block.open').removeClass('open');
    $('.block[data-value="'+val+'"]').addClass('open');
  }else{
    $('.block').addClass('open');
  }
}
```

```css
.block {display:none;}
.block.open {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select onchange="Values()" id="values">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<div data-value="1" class="block open">1</div>
<div data-value="1" class="block open">1</div>
<div data-value="2" class="block open">2</div>
<div data-value="3" class="block open">3</div>
<div data-value="2" class="block open">2</div>
```